# php Undefined Offset in simple function()

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, sizeof

I'm not sure why I am getting an **Undefined Offset Notice** on this:

```
<?php 

$numbers = array('1','2','3');
$total = 0;

for($i=0;$i<=sizeof($numbers); $i++) {
    $total += $numbers[$i];
    echo $total;
}

?>
```

**Output:**

136
Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in E:\php\arrays\array_1.php on **line 17**
6

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your array has three elements at index 0, 1 and 2. There is no element with index 3.

Your loop should stop before it hits that...

```
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($numbers); $i++) {
}
```

Also, checkout [array_sum](http://php.net/array_sum), which might be what you're wanting anyway...

```
$total=array_sum($numbers);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should loop to `<` the size of the array, not `<=`.

```
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($numbers); $i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your condition from `<=` to `<`.

This will add properly:

```
$total += intval($numbers[$i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

turnoff html errors

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
ini_set('html_errors', 'Off');
```